Motor control by PWM signal
I'm trying to control the speed of a small 1020 DC motor (which requires 3.7V for maximum operation) using PWM from an ESP32. I connected the motor through a MOSFET as a switch, and I tested the setup with a 10k resistor. When I connect the resistor, I see the PWM signal working as expected. However, when I replace the resistor with the motor, no voltage seems to be applied across the motor.
Could you explain what might be going wrong and provide a basic explanation of how to control the motor using a  PWM from the ESP32 in the most efficient way?
thank you
I connected a protection diode in parallel with the motor. When I apply 3.7V directly to the gate of the MOSFET, the motor runs at very low power, which suggests that the MOSFET is not fully switching on.
What's puzzling is that when I replace the motor with a 10k resistor, everything seems to work fine. The MOSFET I’m using is a logic-level ('L') version, and its specifications are:
Rds(on) at Vgs = 4V: Id = 21A
Vgs(th) (threshold voltage): min = 1V, max = 2V.
It seems that the low voltage of the PWM signal is the issue, as it's not enough to fully open the MOSFET.
My question is: Is there a recommended way to control a motor like this using an ESP32?
I've been searching for a solution for a long time and would really appreciate any help.

It's not clear why it's not working.  [You might want an antiparallel diode across the motor to absorb any inductive kick.]  What happens if you go to 100% duty cycle? Or just pull the gate to the 3.7 V supply?  Are you sure you have the "L" version of the FET?  Even the L version doesn't have a specified RDSon at 3.3 V, but it should be low enough on resistance to allow the motor to run.

I added details to the question, thank you very much!
